# Tempered representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group. A unitary representation $U$ of $G$ is called tempered if its matrix coefficients lie in the space $L^{2+\epsilon}(G)$ for every $\epsilon>0$. We say that a lattice $\Gamma<G$ is tempered if the representation $$U=\text{orthogonal complement of }L^{2}\left(G/\Gamma\right)^{G}$$ is a tempered representation of $G$. More generally, one can ask what is the minimal $p$ for which the matrix coefficients are in $L^{p+\epsilon}(G)$ for every $\epsilon>0$. I will denote this number by $p(U)$ (for lattices $p(\Gamma)$).

My question concerns the groups $G=SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ and the lattices $\Gamma=SL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$:

1. I understand the for $n=2$, $\Gamma$ is tempered, however I am unable to find any reference in the literature which tells me whether the same holds for $n>2$.
2. If the answer to the first question is negative, what is $p(\Gamma)$? Even a bound would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you just consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-points and not the whole adelic quotient? The problem of estimating the spectral gap on the adelic quotient is known as the generalized Ramanujan conjecture, and some progress has been made towards it.

Regarding question 2, an easy way out is by the fact that higher rank groups are Kazhdan, this representation is isolated from the trivial one simply by the Kazhdan property, and one may bound the matrix coefficients in a uniform way with very good estimates have been done by Hee Oh. P.S. $U$ is usually denoted by $L^{2}_{0}$.